# How to host MVC application in IIS 7.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, hosting

I created a MVC application which is working fine in the local host. I published the project using visual studio to a local folder and uploaded it to the FTP location. But on server its not working.

I followed a couple of tutorials but no result
http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/03/bin-deploy-aspnetmvc.aspx
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntegratingASPNETMVC3IntoExistingUpgradedASPNET4WebFormsApplications.aspx

Is there some good tutorials or could someone help please?
Thanks

Comment: What is not working? What happens? Do you get any error?

Comment: "it's not working" - please specify how exactly it fails. Do you use a database? You might need to set the proper rights on the database file. But there are many other reasons why it can fail.

Comment: Its showing Http 404 Page Not found error..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've had problems getting running. Usually (but not always), installing ASP.NET MVC on the server via the Web Platform Installer seems to fix whatever the problem is. YMMV.

Comment: Yeah I'm pretty sure this is the problem. The MVC libraries and routing stuff isn't built into IIS.

Comment: @Tridus, Actually IIS 7 supports mvc routing, it's IIS 6 that does not.

Answer (score 7):

There are a couple of things that you could check:

1. Check under which application pool the application runs, and check that the application pool uses the `integrated pipeline` instead of `classic`.
2. Check that the `web.config` file contains `<system.webServer>` element. This is the place where the `HttpModules` are registered if you are using the integrated pipeline.
3. Check that the `<modules>` element has the attribute `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests` set to `"true"`. This causes the `HttpModules` to work for all requests, allowing the `UrlRouteModule` to do it's work. You also have to remove and add the HttpModules.

Basically, the `<system.webServer>` section in `web.config` should contain something like this:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
        <remove name="ScriptModule"/>
        <remove name="UrlRoutingModule"/>
        <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web.Routing, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </modules>
    <handlers>
        <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
        <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactory"/>
        <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices"/>
        <remove name="ScriptResource"/>
        <remove name="MvcHttpHandler"/>
        <remove name="UrlRoutingHandler"/>
        <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add name="MvcHttpHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="*.mvc" type="System.Web.Mvc.MvcHttpHandler, System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add name="UrlRoutingHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="UrlRouting.axd" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

**(note that in this case version 1.0 of the MVC platform is used. you should not copy & paste this fragment. It's purely an indication of what it should look like)**

Comment: +1 - This helped me resolve my issue where `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"` was missing from the `modules` element.