# IIS configuration - ASP.NET MVC returns default document on all requests

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

Ok so I have an MVC Web application built in VS 2013. I have been able to host this application successfully through IIS on my local machine with no problems. However I now need to host on a remote machine. I have followed the same steps as I did on my local machine but I keep getting errors.

When I try to browse the web application i get an error HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory. However I have created a default document as the details of this error tell me to and now every time I try to access the application (localhost/MyWebApp) it will just go to that default.html.

However when I specify that I want to go to a specific controller (e.g. localhost/MyWebApp/Home) I get 404 error (HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.)

The machine I am currently trying to host on does not have visual studio installed for various reasons, but I have installed ASP.NET MVC 3 and .NET 4.5 Framework on it. The Default website on the remote machines IIS also already has a classic.net app running successfully.

My thoughts are that:

1 - I am missing some pre-requisite needed to host an asp.net mvc application (possibly something that is installed with visual studio)

Or

2 - Something in IIS is incorrectly configured.

Any advice is welcome as a few hours of goggling has brought up no answers and I have exhausted my knowledge of IIS

**Edit**

Have figured it out and marked it as an answer below.

Comment: Can you show your web.config?

Comment: I have added it to the question.

Comment: Hm - and Global.asax? Including the Route-Config.

Comment: Again its the default. Ill post it if you think that it may be causing an issue but surely if there was a problem with it, the application wouldn't be working when hosted on IIS locally would it?

Comment: This might sound stupid, but I had something similar one time... Is .NET 4.5 correctly installed AND REGISTERED? (call the aspnet_regiis.exe from Framework64 to be sure)

Comment: Yes it seems to be anyway. I executed the aspnet_regiis.exe in framework64/v4.0.30319 and still no change. Doesnt sound that stupid I have a feeling its something stupid anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have finally got it by reading Elian Ebbings anwser in  [How to host MVC application in IIS 7.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064868/how-to-host-mvc-application-in-iis-7-0)

Turns out all that I needed to do was change the web config so that the modules section has the runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests set to true. e.g.

So my web config changed

**From:**

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

**To:**

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 5):

`runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests` should not be used for such things.
[See here](http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2010/06/dont-use-modules-runallmanagedmodulesfo.html) for some details on that.

Most probably, your site is only missing a single module called `UrlRoutingModule`. During installation, MVC nugets installs it into project. [There were some bugs about that, but has been fixed](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/issues/289).

By default, ASP selects content handlers by the extension, like ASPX or JPG present in the URL. Since in MVC usually there's no such thing, the MVC needs this module to perform the routing properly.

The problem is, the routing seems to be not working in your case.

First, be sure that this module is present. Open IIS Management console, go to your page, open Modules section and check if the UrlRoutingModule is listed in the modules. If not, try reinstalling MVC suite. or add it manually to webconfig like it was presented in the article above.

If the module is present, check how exactly is the Site structured.

On IIS there's a slight distinction between "site" and "application". You might deploy your project either as a whole Site, or as an Application contained within some site.

There is a possibility that you are deploying the project as an application and that the module is "turned on" in that application's scope but not on the whole site. If this is the case, you can add simple extra webconfig at the root of the actual Site:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This will enable MVC routing on the whole site and will allow the http://example.com/myapplication/ to be correctly routed despite not having any "default document" set and not having any file extension in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use links like "localhost/MyWebApp/Views/Home/Index.cshtml" in MVC app. Try "localhost/Home/". And check if there are any sites wich were started on 80th port. If MyWebApp is only app which works at 80th port please check was this port added as security rule in remote computer firewall.

Comment: I am already trying to access Localhost/MyWebApp/Home but it returns an error 
HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.

However I have created a default.html as mentioned above and now anytime I try to access anything it just goes to this default html

Comment: Do you read this article? Error message when you visit a Web site that is hosted on IIS 7.0: "HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden"
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942062

Comment: try to repeat steps from this article, if you don't. And I think you should use "localhost/Home/" instead of "Localhost/MyWebApp/Home" if you use 80th port

Comment: Yes I have read that hence why I created the default.html page. The thing is its giving that error because its not navigating to any of my web applications content so it looks for a default document instead. And no I believe I am correct in saying that it should be Localhost/MyWebApp/Home seeing as there is another web application on under the Default website in IIS hence you need to specify that you want the home of "MyWebApp" as opposed to any other application.

Comment: Can you write step by step what are you doing? And can you tell me are you trying to connect to your remote host from your local computer or you trying to get access from remote host browser?

Comment: I have copied across the project to the remote machine. Then I right click the Default web site in IIS and add application pointing it to the project folder and choosing the default ASP.NET V4.0 application pool that comes when you install .NET 4. I then try to browse by right clicking the newly created MyWebApp webapplication and going to Manage Application -> browse. This is the same thing I have done locally and it works fine.

Comment: The problem is in misunderstanding between "Application" and "Site". Your project may have everything set for MVC, but when you deploy it as just an "application", the "site" still does NOT know how to handle MVC-like requests and routes them like Classic ASP.Net would. When you installed VisualStudio+MVC on your dev machine, the installers have done some trocks. On a new machine, you have to set it properly. In short, you need to add `UrlRoutingModule` to the Site, that is, `DefaultWebSite` in your case. See my answer and linked article for more details.

Answer (score 0):

## ASP MVC 4 (run IIS and edit code same time):

Editing a `.cs` file while IIS is running sometimes causes problems, but it is possible to run IIS and edit the code.

Just right click on a `cshtml` file and then click "view in browser". It will run IIS and then you can edit any .cs file and see the output of any 'view' at the same time.