# How do I identify the start page in MVC4 app?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I should preface this question by saying I have never done any MVC work before.  My assignment is to move an MVC project from one server to another, and I am not sure what to set the IIS start page to.  I have done some research an reviewed the app, and I found this code in the RouteConfig.cs file:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "KOOL", action = "AdvancedSearch", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

Does this mean the start page is Default.aspx?  If so, where would I find it?  I don't see it in the project (it is a large project with lots of folders).

Comment: I would be surprised if you found any `.aspx` in an MVC solution.

Comment: Hi, Melancia.  Unfortunately, I know so little about MVC, that is news to me.  I guess I assumed it is somewhat similar to an ASP.NET app, but with a different structure.  Can you elaborate on where I might find the start page?

Comment: I don't actually think you need to set anything on IIS for the website to work. It should be all defined already on a base controller of sorts.

Comment: Anything you try to set will be ignored. It would be valid just if you had an ASP.NET webforms solution. Give it a try without any changes.

Comment: This post might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21777522/iis-configuration-asp-net-mvc-returns-default-document-on-all-requests

Comment: Thank you!  I tried, but am getting a Login failed for user 'DOMAIN\SERVERNAME$' error.  That's obviously not caused by the start page, so I'm going to operate on the assumption the start page is good and try to resolve this problem.  i will mark your comment as the answer.  Appreciate that.